# Upgrade Vault from 1.6.2 to 1.10.9 Error on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault, vault

I already have install Vault Version 1.6.2 on my Kubernetes, using pod Vault-0, but the version is too old to configure, but myvault works and already running on my kubernetes,
when i want to upgrade with helm i got error **CrashLoopBackOff**

I install my vault with this command :

```
helm install vault banzaicloud-stable/vault -n vault
```

so i want to upgrade with this command :

```
 helm upgrade vault banzaicloud-stable/vault -n vault \
   --set "image.tag=1.10.9"
```

my vault has already upgrade like this :

[image: Here's the image]

when i check with this command :

```
kubectl get pods -n vault
```

I got error CrashLoopBackOff on my **vault-unsealer** container

when i decribe the error i got this :

```
{"level":"fatal","msg":"error initializing vault: error testing keystore before init: error getting secret for key 'vault-test': secrets \"bank-vaults\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:vault:vault\" cannot get resource \"secrets\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"","time":"2022-12-19T09:31:26Z"}
```

Can someone help me please with this error ? what should i do

Note : I already have **vault-test** secret on my kubernetes secret

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is permission denied because ClusterRoleBinding must be bound to the [service account](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/auth/kubernetes).

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-tokenreview-binding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: vault-auth      #Give your service account name here.
    namespace: default  #Give your Kubernetes Namespace here.
```

If you have cluster role binding check whether you have specified the same service account in your deployment and cluster role binding.The service account that you wish to use for your pod can be specified in your deployments. The default service account in each namespace will be used if a specific service account is not specified in a deployment. This default service account can also be granted permission to authenticate.Some service account will be created for token review so verify the same.

For crashloop backoff attach logs if possible, attaching [troubleshooting doc](https://docs.microfocus.com/doc/UCMDB_Containerized/2021.05/TsPodsCrashLoopBackOff) for your reference.